# REGEX : try to capture the head of a each groups and the content of each groups

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a data file like that :

```
[linux]
foo
faafaa

fii
[windows]

faa fii@@
<tag1>fuu</tag1>
foo1234

[osname3]
faa faa
[osname4]
fiifoo
```

I'm lookin for capture all os name and the content inner each os title. **The number of os and the contents are variables** and **one content can contain all existing caracters**. The expected result after the REGEX is something like this :

```markdown
Match1 : 
    Groupe1 : 'linux'
    Groupe2 : 'foo
faafaa'

Match2 : 
    Groupe1 : 'windows'
    Groupe2 : '
faa fii@@
<tag1>fuu</tag1>
foo1234
'

Match3 : 
    Groupe1 : 'osname3'
    Groupe2 : 'faa faa'

Match4 : 
    Groupe1 : 'osname4'
    Groupe2 : 'fiifoo'
```

My last try is this REGEX : `(?:\[([\S ]+)\]\n((?:[\s\S\n])(?!\n\[))*)`

But, [as you see here](https://regex101.com/r/56LKKv/1), the result isn't what I'm looking for :

[image]

The issue is here : `(?:[\s\S\n])(?!\n\[))*`

If I translate what I want to do here : "please REGEX, can you capture all caracters (`[\s\S\n]`) but stop before the pattern `(\n\[)`" ?

But I don't have what I expected to and I don't understand why...

Lastly, for some reasons, my REGEX needs to be usable with php and javascript

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Why isn't `fii` matched with `linux`, but all that other stuff is matched with `windows`, but it's after an empty line?

Comment: its a good question ! i don't understand too haha

Comment: No I mean your expected output - it's not consistent.

Comment: Would [this](https://regex101.com/r/PHluRV/1) work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that this regex will hold for more complex cases you want to match, but it seems to pass the given input:

```js
const regex = /(?:\[(\w+)\])\n((?:[^[]*\n|[^[]))*/g;
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ match lines that do not contain '['
//                  ^^^^^ match inside brackets
```

However, this input looks like [TOML](https://toml.io/en/) - so in that case, please use a TOML parser instead of regex :)

Comment: hmm I forget the case where a content may contain the chars [ or ]. Ill try to improve your regex but if you have a solution, I take !

Comment: @mickmackusa Seems like it - I just copied their regex flags to my answer.